# Access an iframe with no id which is inside a div(div has id)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a div with id "test". Inside it is an iframe which has no id. I need to access the body contents of this iframe. How to do it using JS/Jquery?

Comment: Is the iframe source from the same domain as the main page?

Comment: Yeah. Actually the iframe doesn't display any other HTML page. It is editable using an external JS.

Comment: Body contents means which html control you want to access from iframe page to main page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access it like this:

```
$('#test>iframe').contents.find('body') // This will get you body tag
```

Comment: Totally did not work

Answer (score 0):

jquery will do it.

```
 var objiframe=$('#test').find('iframe');
```

you'll get `iframe` in `objiframe`

then use `objiframe` with selector to get or set attribute and contents of iframe.